# Add library builded with meson to Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qmake, meson-build

I have a library that I build using meson and i want to add that library in my Qt project. So, only with one `make` call, being able to build the library with meson and link to it.

So far, I tried adding the library to the root directory and in the makefile doing this.

```
# Define custom build
mylib.commands = meson setup $$PWD/mylib/ build && ninja -C build
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += mylib
POST_TARGETDEPS += mylib

# Link library
unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$OUT_PWD/build/source/ -lmylib

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/mylib/includes
INCLUDEPATH += $$OUT_PWD/build/source
DEPENDPATH += $$OUT_PWD/build/source
```

This build my library using meson and link with success when I build and run from QtCreator. The build meson directory is created inside the build Qt directory and the link works. However, when I try to build from console using `make` command, the library cannot be found. How should I link mylib in this case?

Comment: Did you run `qmake` first to regenerate the Makefile?

Comment: Yes, first qmake myproject.pro, then make

Comment: then clearly QtCreator invokes qmake differently than you do. For example, your `mylib.commands` seems to assume a specific working directory. but your link instruction a different one.